# function Component receive props but doesn't render it

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, react-props

### Situation:

first, I fetch **imgs** list from database:

```
{imgs:
    [
        {_id: '...',img:'***.png'},
        ...,
    ]
}
```

then, signature **img.src** using **ali-oss-hook**, results like:

```
{imgs:
    [
        {_id:'...', img: '***.png', src: 'signatured-http-address'}
        ...,
    ]
}
```

then, pass the imgs to **PictureList** component ：

```
<PictureList imgs={images}
```

**PictureList** receive the new props,but didn't render it

```
const PictureList = ({ imgs }) => {
 return (
 <ul>
 {imgs.map((i) => (
   <img key={i._id} src={i.src} alt="pic" />
 ))}
 </ul>
 );
}
export default PictureList
```

### Code

#### Picture.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { useAlioss } from '../../hooks/oss-hook'
import PictureList from '../../components/PictureList'

import './style.less'

const Pictures = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [signatured, setSignatured] = useState(false)
  const [results, setResults] = useState()
  const [images, setImages] = useState([])

  const { allowUrl } = useAlioss()
 
  const resultsDoSetRef = useRef(false)
  
  async function getImages() {
    try {
      const dbResponse = await fetch(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/upload/images`
      );

      const resu = await dbResponse.json();

      setResults(resu)
      resultsDoSetRef.current = true

    } catch (e) {
      console.log("get images failed")
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
      console.log("get images done!")
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getImages();
  }, [])
  
  async function signatureUrl(raw) {
    setSignatured(false)
    try {
      let tempImgs = []

      raw.imgs.forEach((r) => {
        allowUrl(r.img).then((res) => {
          r.img = res;
          tempImgs.push(r)
        });
      });

      setImages(tempImgs);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("signature failed",e)
    } finally {
      setSignatured(true)
      console.log("signature done!")
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (resultsDoSetRef.current) {
      resultsDoSetRef.current = false
      signatureUrl(results);
    }
  },[results])
  
  return (
    <div className="picture">
      {loading ? <h1>Loading</h1> : <PictureList imgs={images} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pictures
```

#### PictureList.js

```
const PictureList = ({ imgs }) => {
 return (
 <ul>
 {imgs.map((i) => (
   <img key={i._id} src={i.src} alt="pic" />
 ))}
 </ul>
 );
}
export default PictureList
```

[chrome react devTool component shows props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBPs9.jpg)

[chrome devTool element shows empty PictureList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3bxo.jpg)

In **chrome devTool** **react component** shows right props, but the PictureList component still empty `<ul></ul>`.

Which part is wrong?

Comment: The `<PictureList />` component looks okay, do you have any error on the console?

Comment: @norbitrial there is no error on the console!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PictureList.js, you are receving "imgs" as the arugument of the function, this is not the same as property you passed in

```
<PictureList imgs={images}
```

This "imgs" is actually an object that has a property imgs, so your code will become:

```
const PictureList = ({ imgs }) => {
 return (
 <ul>
 {imgs.imgs.map((i) => (
   <img key={i._id} src={i.src} alt="pic" />
 ))}
 </ul>
 );
}
export default PictureList
```

P.S : Just a suggestion, generally props(or something similarly descriptiove)  is used as the parameter argument, so your code will be something like this:

```
const PictureList = ({ props }) => {
     return (
     <ul>
     {props.imgs.map((i) => (
       <img key={i._id} src={i.src} alt="pic" />
     ))}
     </ul>
     );
    }
    export default PictureList
```

Comment: `const PictureList = props => { console.log(props.imgs)  return (<ul>{props.imgs.map((i) => (...);}</ul>`. I tried to pass a general **props** as the parameter, and add a **console.log**.  _imgs_ prints on console as wish, even printed two times:`[]
0:{ _id: "...", img: "....jpg", src: "..."}
1: {_id: "...", img: "....jpg", src: "..."}
2: {_id: "...", img: "***.jpg", src: "..."}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)` PS: I changed the Picture : `allowUrl(r.img).then((res) => {
          r.src = res;
          tempImgs.push(r)
        })` add a **src** in img object.

Answer (score 0):

In **Picture --signatureUrl()** method, `raw.imgs.forEach()` returns a bounch of **promises**, these promises can't resolve all at once.

When `setImages(tempImgs)` ,the **images** in **useState hook** receive a empty array first, then push new image to **images** array when `raw.imgs.forEach()` returned **promise** resolve a  new **image item**.

So, we must wait all `allowUrl(r.img)` promises resolved, then `setImages(tempImgs)`.

```
function signatureUrl(raw) {
    const tasks = raw.imgs.map(i => allowUrl(i.img))
    Promise.all(tasks).then(values => {
      let resultImgs = raw.imgs.map((t, index) => ({ ...t, src: values[index] }));

      setImages(resultImgs)
    })
  }
```

**PS:** Solution do works, but all analizes may be wrong, for reference only.